# How to get annotations of a caller method from another class

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, annotations, stack-trace

I am using `jdk1.8.0_221` and I want to load specific configuration inside the constructor of super class based on calling two different types of methods. I am seeking for the best practice and preferably a convenient approach.

Due to simplification, I have simulated the code situation as the following snippet:

```
package test;
public class A extends Z{
    @Test
    @Marker1
    public void f1() {
        Z.g();
    }
    @Test
    @Marker2
    public void f2() {
        Z.g();
    }
}

package test;
public class B extends Z{
    @Test
    @Marker1
    public void f3() {
        Z.g();
    }
    @Test
    @Marker2
    public void f4() {
        Z.g();
    }
}

package core;
public class Z{
    public Z() {
        //I want to determine here that which type of method calls this constructor
        //The caller could be Marker1 or Marker2
        //And based on the caller, load the corresponding configuration
    }
    public static void g(){
        //some code goes here
    }
}
```

**Note1:** There are many methods from different classes that calls `Z.g()`, so I could not use the explicit name of class to get methods and its annotations.

**Note2:** All of configurations should be done inside the constructor of super class of Z.

**Note3:** The `g()` method is not necessarily static.

I have tried the following snippet but `getMethodName()` return always `<init>`:

```
public Z() throws NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException{
    StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    StackTraceElement ste = stElements[3];// or stElements[2]
    Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(ste.getClassName());
    String methodName = ste.getMethodName();
    Method method = aClass.getMethod(methodName);
    Annotation[] annotations = aClass.getAnnotations();
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        if (annotation.getClass().equals(Marker1.class)) {
             //load conf1
             break;
         } else if (annotation.getClass().equals(Marker2.class)) {
             //load conf2
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

Also, I have tried many solutions in stackoverflow and other communities which not worked properly.

Comment: This is not a good design.  A method should behave the same regardless of who calls it.  If you want different behavior, give your method an argument that specifies that behavior.  In your case, you probably want callers to pass the path of a configuration file or configuration object as an argument.

Comment: Dear @VGR , this is impossible in my case. There  are many complicated relations among my classes that I ignore them here for simplification. Indeed, class A extends Z and all of my configuration settings should be done inside the constructor of Z (equivalent to my g() method).

Comment: It would be worth the time to fix it.  Debugging such code will be a nightmare.  But if you really cannot or will not change it, I would suggest creating a global static state object.  If you are using multiple threads, you will need to protect this global object with synchronization or a lock.

Comment: what if more than one function like that will be called before constructor?

Comment: But anyways, you need to call this code in that "g" method, and then store type in some static state like @VGR suggested. Also in your code you should use `method.isAnnotationPresent(Marker1.class)` instead

Answer (score 0):

The result you get, is precisely telling you what is happening. Neither of your methods is invoking the constructor.

All of your methods have the form

```
@Test
@MarkerN
public void fX() {
    Z.g();
}
```

so they contain an invocation of the `static` method `g()` of class `Z`. But no instantiation of `Z`.

Instead, your classes `A` and `B` are subclasses of `Z`. Since you didn’t declare explicit constructors for them, the compiler generates default constructors for them, like

```
public class A extends Z {

    public A() {
        super(); // here, the constructor of Z gets called
    }


// the other methods …

}
```

and so, the reflective lookup will tell you that the invocation of `Z`’s constructor happens inside a method named `<init>`, which is `A`’s constructor, resp. `B`’s constructor for `B`.

It would be different if the methods did `new Z().g()`, but that would make the questionable design of relying on a constructor being executed before a `static` method invocation even worse.

This issue should be solved on the framework side, which is doing both, instantiating `A` and `B` and invoking the methods `f1()` to `f4()` on them. E.g. with JUnit 5, the solution would look like:

```
package test;

import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;

public class A {
    @BeforeEach
    public void prepare(TestInfo ti) {
        Z.loadConfiguration(ti.getTestMethod().get());
    }
    @Test
    @Marker1
    public void f1() {
        Z.g();
    }
    @Test
    @Marker2
    public void f2() {
        Z.g();
    }
}

class Z {
    public static void loadConfiguration(AnnotatedElement e) {
        if(e.isAnnotationPresent(Marker1.class)) {
            System.out.println("Marker1");
        }
        else if(e.isAnnotationPresent(Marker2.class)) {
            System.out.println("Marker2");
        } 
    }
    public static void g() {
        System.out.println("Z.g()");
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Marker1 {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Marker2 {}
```

```
Marker1
Z.g()
Marker2
Z.g()
```